# Getting distribution of squared coordinate on a sphere?

Tags: probability-or-statistics

Suppose $\mathbf{x}$ is on a surface of [n-sphere](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/N-sphere), how do I get the distribution of $x_1^2$?

Distribution of $x_1$ is [shifted Beta](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3019736/998) so we can use `TransformedDistribution` to get pdf of $x_1^2$. However, this seems to require specific values of $n$, I'm wondering if there's a straightforward way to get formula for generic $n$.

```
n = 10;

$Assumptions = {0 < x < 1};
SF = StringForm;
dist = BetaDistribution[n/2, n/2];
squaredDist = 
  TransformedDistribution[(2 x - 1)^2, x \[Distributed] dist];
pdf = Refine@PDF[squaredDist, x]
plot = Plot @@ {PDF[squaredDist, x], {x, 0, 1}, 
    PlotLabel -> SF["Distribution for ``-sphere", n], 
    PlotLegends -> {"true"}, AxesLabel -> {"x", "f(x)"}};

hist = SmoothHistogram[
   First[#]^2 & /@ RandomPoint[Sphere[n + 1], 10000], 
   PlotLegends -> {"simulated"}, PlotStyle -> {Gray, Dashed}];
Show[plot, hist]
```

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This problem is presented in a more complicated manner than is needed. It is also actually a very nice illustration of the power of *Mathematica*.

The problem is conceptually simple. We are [given](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2977867/x-coordinate-distribution-on-the-n-sphere/3019736#3019736) that random variable $X$ has pdf $f(x)$:

[image]

We seek the pdf of $Y=X^2$.

The characteristic function of $Y=X^2$ is:

[image]

where I am using the `Expect` function from the *mathStatica* package for *Mathematica*.

Inverting the characteristic function yields the pdf of $Y$, as a general function of $n$:

[image]

All done. Note that this is a $\text{Beta}(\frac12, \frac{n}{2})$ distribution.

Example and check:

[image]

Comment: Thanks! Curious if this is how you got formula for chi-squared * beta [question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/619032/distribution-of-product-of-beta-and-chi-squared) .... IE, multiplying two characteristic functions, then take inverse Fourier

Answer (score 2):

You do not need to set `n` to a value.

```
n =.;
dist = BetaDistribution[n/2, n/2];
squaredDist = TransformedDistribution[(2 x - 1)^2, x \[Distributed] dist];
pdf = Refine@PDF[squaredDist, x]
```

> [image: Mathematica graphics]

The above evaluates in less than a minute on my laptop and gives a general solution for an n-sphere.

Next plot with

```
Manipulate[
 Show[
  Plot[pdf /. n -> nn, {x, 0, 1}
   , PlotRange -> Full
   , PlotLabel -> SF["Distribution for ``-sphere", nn]
   , PlotLegends -> {"PDF"}
   , ScalingFunctions -> "Log"
   , AxesLabel -> {"x", "f(x)"}
   ]
  ,
  SmoothHistogram[
   First[#]^2 & /@ RandomPoint[Sphere[nn + 1], 10000]
   , {Automatic, {"Bounded", {0, 1}, "Gaussian"}}
   , PlotRange -> Full
   , ScalingFunctions -> "Log"
   , PlotLegends -> {"Simulated"}
   , PlotStyle -> {Thick, Gray, Dashed}
   ]
  ]
 , {{nn, 2, "n"}, 2, 20, 1}
 ]
```

> [image]

You should use Formal Symbols (e.g. <kbd>esc</kbd>$n<kbd>esc</kbd> for symbols needed in formulas to prevent unintended setting of `n` that will cause issues.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Ah, looks like I didn't wait long enough. Thanks for the FormalN trick, haven't seen that before